# How can I add Subscribe Message subject line token?

Tags: webform-civicrm, email, tokens, confirmation, subscribe

When users sign up to several mailing lists via our webform, they receive automatic 'Subscribe Message' confirmation emails for double opt-in. If they have attempted to sign up to two groups at the same time, these emails have the same subject line and get nested together in Gmail so that users are often only clicking one of the group confirmation links because it's not immediately obvious there are two emails for them to open/click.

I've tried to add the {subscribe.group} token to the automated messages subject line so that the email subject lines will be differentiated, but this doesn't seem to work (the token works in the body of the email itself, but not in the subject line).

Is there a way to add this token to the subject line, or to differentiate these automatic emails some other way so that Gmail etc. don't nest them together in the same thread? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to civicrm stackexchange. Are you using Drupal 7 or 8?  The emails being triggered by the same form submission? or different submissions of the same webform? Do you need to use the double opt in to confirm subscription to the group? Or is one confirmation (to confirm a valid email address enough?)