# tokens not working in CiviMail automated message subject lines

Tags: civimail, tokens, message-templates

I have the same problem as in this post: [How can I add Subscribe Message subject line token?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35917/how-can-i-add-subscribe-message-subject-line-token)

But that post has no resolution.

Users can sign up to as many as 5 mailing groups on our form, so can receive multiple confirmation messages at once. Having the group name in the subject of each message would be helpful.

I've tried several different tokens, not just {subscribe.group} (the one I need) and none are evaluated. All tokens work fine in the message body. Is this expected behavior, or a bug?

System info: Civi 5.58.1 running on Drupal 9.

Comment: I can't find any mention of this in the bug tracker, and it's still an issue for me.  Would really like to know if this is expected behavior or a bug.

Comment: Maybe this extension could be an alternative: https://docs.civicrm.org/newsletter/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue that could match with your description. Check it at [Some contact core tokens stopped working in 5.43 RC](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2907)

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I did come across this issue in my search, but disregarded it because all my tokens seem to be working except when they're in the subject line. But reading farther there may be more to it. I'll do some more testing, thanks for the heads up. I'll come back with the results.

Comment: OK so I've tested in an environment with extensions GDPR, Flexmailer, and Mosaico all in various states of enabled/disabled. Contact tokens indeed do not work anywhere. However, the action tokens {subscribe.group} and {subscribe.url} work consistently inside the message body, but never in the subject line. I'm still not 100% sure this is the same issue (contact vs. action tokens) but appreciate the heads up.  I'm surprised this isn't a bigger issue, as token functionality seems to be pretty integral to mass mailing functions.

Comment: @minbori, I encourage you to open a new issue or leave a comment [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2907), describing your case. I think they may be related.